# Clearing SSL exceptions in Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, ssl-certificate

Some iPhone users are experiencing a SSL cert warning when visiting my site with mobile Safari. After they dismiss the warning the first time it does not reoccur. How can I clear these SSL dismissals in order to retrigger the warning for testing purposes?

thanks

Comment: Similar: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130612/how-do-you-remove-ssl-certificate-exceptions-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few years have passed but there still isn't a good answer on the web.
I'm sure it's not relevant for OP but may be for someone else.

As of 13.7 here's how I managed to do this:

0. close any instances of the website in Safari and close Safari [may be not required but just to be safe]
1. reset network settings [settings > general > reset > reset network settings]
2. if you visit the site it will show / not show the warning intermittently [not show if you type the website in new tab, show on refresh]
3. go to website data [general > safari > advanced > website data]
4. wait for the list to load
5. search for the website and scroll to the left on the offending website